# Basic matrix algebra in SVD

Tags: matrices, statistics, svd

For my math course I'm reading about SVD in Principal Component Analysis (Abdi et al., 2010), I get stuck in (I think) a simple matrix algebra. In the text, equation (1) define SVD as: 
 **$X = PΔQ^T$** (Eq.1) 
 and factor scores **$F$** is defined as:
 **$F = PΔ$** (Eq. 2) 
 The matrix **$Q$** gives the coefficients of the linear combinations used to compute the factors scores. This matrix can also be interpreted as a projection matrix because multiplying **X** by **$Q$** gives the values of the projections of the observations on the principal components. This can be shown by combining Eqs. 1 and 2 as:
 **$F = PΔ = PΔQ^TQ = XQ$** 
 I need help to see how to combining Eq1 and 2 I get **$F=XQ$**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that Q is an orthogonal matrix ($QQ^T = Q^TQ = I$). Since we have $X = P \Delta Q^T $ and $ F = P \Delta $. Then by substitution:
$$X = F Q^T $$
$$X Q= F Q^T Q$$
Then
$$X Q = F $$

More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#:%7E:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20the%20singular,extension%20of%20the%20polar%20decomposition.).

Comment: Really thanks!!